# Can a logical formula that is a contradiction be represented as Disjunctive Normal Form?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

Hi I was trying to solve this math problem in mathematics.

> Obtain the D.N.F, C.N.F, P.D.N.F, P.C.N.F of the following expression : $(Q \to P) \land (\lnot P \land Q)$

I understand that there is no **Particular Disjunctive Normal Form** for this statement, as the the statement is a contradiction.

However, I'm not sure if it's suffice to say that there is no D.N.F for this statement as well.

I understand that the definition of a Disjunctive Normal Form is "a disjunction of one or more conjunctions of one or more literals"(from wikipedia). And that "All logical formulas can be converted into an equivalent disjunctive normal form"(again from wikipedia).

But I was wondering if $(P \land \lnot P) \lor (Q \land \lnot Q)$ could be an answer. As each of the conjunctions hold more than one literals can I say that this is the D.N.F of the given contradiction?

P.S. Pls correct my errors in the argument above. It would be more than welcome. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: DNF stands for *disjunctive normal form*.

Comment: Define "Distributive Normal Form".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P \land \neg P$ is in DNF

It may not look like it, but it really is.

Here's the thing: a statement is in DNF iff it is a *generalized* disjunction of *generalized* conjunctions of literals. And by *generalized* we mean that the disjunction/conjunction can have *any* number of disjuncts/conjuncts. So the above statement is in fact a disjunction ... of exactly one disjunct.

Indeed, even a statement like $P$ is in DNF: it is a disjunction of one disjunct $P$,  which is itself a conjunction of one conjunct $P$, which is a literal. By similar reasoning, $P$ is in CNF as well.

In fact, $P \land \neg P$ is both a DNF and a CNF of your original formula. It is in CNF since it is a conjunction of two conjuncts, each of which is a disjunction of one literal.

Comment: Since DNF form shows this is a contradiction, as shown in my post and the proof there, of course, one can say, well $\bot \equiv A \land \lnot A$, or $\text{foo } \land \lnot\text{foo}$, etc. which is in DNF.  Hardly what the exercise seems to be asking.

Answer (score -1):

$\begin{align}(Q \to P) \land (\lnot P \land Q) &\equiv (\lnot Q \lor P) \land(\lnot P \land Q)\tag{def. $\to$}\\ \\
&\equiv (\lnot Q \land (\lnot P \land Q)) \lor (P\land (\lnot P \land Q))\tag{distribution}\\ \\
&\equiv (\lnot Q \land \lnot P \land Q) \lor (P \land \lnot P \land Q)\tag {assoc.}\\ \\
&\equiv ((\lnot Q \land Q)\land \lnot P) \lor ((P\land \lnot P) \land Q))\tag{comm.+assoc.}\\ \\
&\equiv (\bot \land \lnot P) \lor (\bot\land Q)\\ \\
&\equiv \bot \lor \bot\\ \\
&\equiv \bot\end{align}$

The third line above is in Disjunctive Normal Form.

Comment: If $\bot$ isn't in the vocabulary, then lines 5 and 6 can't be in disjunctive normal form.

Comment: The usual method for converting a truth table into a DNF works even for contradictions if one adopts the natural (I'd even say "correct") convention that $\bot$ is the disjunction of the empty set of formulas.